# Connecting to Github Organization Account

Tags: cli, github, devopscenter

Great news! Salesforce DevOps Center is Generally Available.

I am struggling to connect it to a repository owned by Organization.

DevOps Center guide says the following:

GitHub repos owned by an organization aren’t visible in DevOps Center until an *organization account owner provides access.*

1. Authenticate to GitHub through DevOps Center.
2. In GitHub, provide access to *both Salesforce Integration applications.*
   One provides integration across your GitHub repo, DevOps Center, and development environments (scratch orgs and sandboxes). The other provides integration across your GitHub repo, DevOps Center, and production orgs.
   [...](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.devops_center_org_owns_github_repo.htm&type=5)

So, I am stuck. In personal Github Account I can see only *one* Salesforce Integration Application and I grant access to the org via this OAuth App.

[image]

As a result I cannot create a project with repo owned by my Organization's GitHub Account, though the repo itself is being created.
Neither I can create a project and link to existing repo, I keep getting error message that the repo does not exist.

Please help.

**UPD:** My personal account *is the owner* of the organization account, and I am a member of Developers team that has read/write access to the repo.

Comment: Who is the owner of the gir repo that's getting created?

Comment: The Organization Account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the resolution was under my nose.
Since my GitHub Organization Account has an IP Allow list enabled, I have to add DevOps Center IP addresses to this list and **a range of relevant Salesforce IP addresses**.

Initially I forgot to enlist my Salesforce's IP range, that's why the package was able to create repo/project, but it was not able to see existing repos.